# Can I select the layout to use for a page with Wyam?

Tags: wyam

I'm working on a theme for [Wyam](https://wyam.io/) and I'm wondering if there's a way to set the layout that should be used in the markdown file for a particular page. As far as I have seen so far, it seems that each page created with markdown uses `_Layout.cshtml`

To be more specific. I'm creating an "about.md" page, which has a different layout then then other (default) pages.

So what I would like to do is use metadata to select the layout. For example

```
Layout: _About.cshtml
```

or

```
Layout: _About
```

Is this possible with Wyam?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In A Razor File**

Pages in the Wyam recipes (I'm assuming you're using either the blog or docs recipe) are processed by Razor. The use of a `_Layout.cshtml` is by convention in the recipe, but alternate layouts can be specified using standard Razor syntax. You can do so by placing the following at the top of the about page `.cshtml` file (*under* your front matter):

```
@{
    Layout = "_About.cshtml";
}
```

**In A Markdown File**

Markdown files are also processed by the Razor engine, so the technique above *would* work if it weren't for the Markdown processor escaping the `@` symbol. There's really no good way around that, and the simple answer to your question is you can't specify an alternate layout for a Markdown file.

However, one of the advantages of using a code-driven generator like Wyam is that you have a lot of control. In this case, you can replace the RenderPages pipeline with one that will do exactly what you want. Add the following to your `wyam.config` file:

```
int index = Pipelines.IndexOf(Blog.RenderPages);
Pipelines.Remove(Blog.RenderPages);
Pipelines.Insert(index, Blog.RenderPages,
    (IPipeline)new Wyam.Web.Pipelines.RenderPages(
        Blog.RenderPages,
        new Wyam.Web.Pipelines.RenderPagesSettings
        {
            Pipelines = new string[] { "Pages" },
            Layout = (doc, ctx) => doc.String("Layout", "/_Layout.cshtml")
        }));
```

Then you'll be able to add a "Layout" value as front matter exactly like you wrote in your question.

This was a good idea in general, so I've also opened an issue to add this behavior to the recipe by default.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I already knew that. What I would like to do is select a template in the `.md` file. I'll change my question to make it more clear.

Comment: @JohanVergeer Gotcha - I edited my answer to show how you could do this by replacing the pipeline from your config file